# Change dynamically the event callback parameter of a Blazor component

Tags: c#, callback, blazor

I have a Blazor component that can take various parameters, including an EventCallback.

The code below will work, but I cannot change the callback:

```
<ModalDialog
        Title="@_dialogTitle" 
        Message="@_dialogMessage" 
        Layout="@_dialogType" 
        OnClose="DummyCallback" />
```

What I want to do is something like this

```
<ModalDialog
        Title="@_dialogTitle" 
        Message="@_dialogMessage" 
        Layout="@_dialogType" 
        OnClose="@_callback" />
```

combined with

```
private EventCallback<bool> _callback;
```

and depending on the state of the parent component I want to assign a different callback for the ModalDialog component:

```
_callback = DummyCallback;
```

but this gives me an error:

```
CS0428  Cannot convert method group 'DummyCallback' to non-delegate type 'EventCallback<bool>'. Did you intend to invoke the method?        C:\xxxxx\xxxxx.razor    161
```

I could include this component more than once, and each component would take a different callback, but here I would like to include this component only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have the wrong type for `_callback`

Try this:

`private Action<bool> _callback;`

You will be able to do change the target now to any method that accepts a bool.